# module.exports in nodejs - fn vs object

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following two alternate representations of what I thought was the same functionality.

apiRegistry1.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    var apiRegistry = {};
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./apis');
    for (var index in files) {
        var fileName = files[index];
        var module = fileName.split('.')[0];
        apiRegistry[module] = require('../apis/' + module);
    }
    // console.log(apiRegistry) --> Prints {key: moduledef ..}
    return apiRegistry;
};
```

vs

apiregistry2.js

```
var apiRegistry = {};
var files = fs.readdirSync('./apis');
for (var index in files) {
    var fileName = files[index];
    var module = fileName.split('.')[0];
    apiRegistry[module] = require('../apis/' + module);
}

// console.log(apiRegistry) --> Prints {key: moduledef ..}
module.exports = apiRegistry;
```

server.js

```
var apiRegistry1 = require('./includes/apiregistry1')(); // returns {key: moduledef ..}
var apiRegistry2 = require('./includes/apiregistry2'); //returns {}
```

apiRegistry1 behaves as I would expect, but 2 doesn't. On some level it makes sense that 1 is a function and is evaluated when it's called, and that's why it works but I don't understand why printing the value *within* the module always works, but referencing outside of it doesn't. Is there something fundamental about how require works that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var module = fileName.split('.')[0];`

is the culprit.

Because of how scoping works in JavaScript, that `module` variable isn't local to the `for` loop but instead the whole file.  Thus, when you use it at the end:

`module.exports = apiRegistry;`

you are setting the `exports` property on your own `module` variable instead of the one node expects you to use.  Changing to using another variable name solves your problem:

```
var apiRegistry = {};
var files = fs.readdirSync('./apis');
for (var index in files) {
    var fileName = files[index];
    var myModule = fileName.split('.')[0];
    apiRegistry[myModule] = require('../apis/' + myModule);
}

// console.log(apiRegistry) --> Prints {key: moduledef ..}
module.exports = apiRegistry;
```

Comment: Ah duh, should've caught that. Thanks!